# Ultra-operations numbers (polynomials)

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, root-systems

After Bring's root article, I became interested in understanding the theory of ultra numbers and their operations. There are very few vague concepts about these numbers on the Internet. I would be grateful for literature or sources detailing these numbers or actions.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Bring's root article"? There's the Bring radical or ultraradical, which is the unique solution of $x^5 + x + a = 0$. Is that what you're talking about?